# Creating a target group for a alb (application load balancer )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

When creating a target group for ALB into a private r public vpc for port `8080`, why is that I need to mention path, for a regular html page we have `.index` file but when we have an application running at port `8080`, how can we define the path?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)?  If not, it's worth reading up on if you're working with infrastructure.

An Application Load Balancer is a Layer 7 Load Balancer.  This means it communicates at the software application level.

The reason this is useful becomes clear if you wish to route traffic to a particular path that is exposed by your app i.e. https://yourapp:8080/api (in this case your path would be `/api`)

In your case though, it sounds like it should be sufficient to set the path value to `/`

Answer (score 0):

ALB target Groups are set of instances to forward request based on Listeners defined under ALB configuration.

Target Groups registered instances healthcheck state is maintained by checking for success of /healthcheck.html path on the specific port.

Either http or https path representation is same.  It's **/api** which responds with 200 Ok to mark the server is healthy.

[image: Target Group Creation]